# Is it possible for this enderman to escape this cage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible for my pet ender man "Bob" to escape its cage? I heard that they cant teleport out of enclosed areas, but I also heard they can pick up smooth stone blocks which might mean it can make the cage not fully enclosed anymore and teleport out. it does have a name tag fyi.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, your enderman can teleport his outside the cage... But deplace blocks of the cage is less possible.
If your enderman is not attacked, he (maybe) can't teleport his outside...

I hope that I answered your question !   :-)

Comment: I kinda get what your saying I think but since I posted this question he hasn't escaped and I even used my AFK fish farm for 2 hours and he still hasn't escaped. The only activity he has done is place the grass and then pick up the grass and that's the only thing he has done.